# Miniseries where a man and woman investigate supernatural happenings in a small town

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, mystery

I saw it back in Russia around 2007, but it may have been filmed a year or two before that in its home country. I only saw a dub, but the original language was English. It looked like it was made in the early 2000s. The action took place in modern times.

What I can recall of the premise is thus:

1. Two of the episodes featured the following villains:

   - A man-eating tree. Its wood was used to build several houses, trinkets and other items which ended up in the town. They caused people to hallucinate visions of their deceased loved ones. After the victims dropped their guard the tree showed it's true form and drained them of their blood. It posed as the male character's fiancée during the episode. The first victim was an elderly woman who was thinking her beloved pet (a dog?) had come back to life.
   - A banshee. A pair of twin girls lived in a huge estate located in this town sometime in the 19th(?) century and died under mysterious circumstances. It turns out one or both of them was entombed alive inside the estate and became or always was a banshee. What appears to be death made an appearence at the end of the episode to encourage the girl to let go of her anger and move on into the afterlife.
2. The main character is a woman who is either new to the town in which the show takes place or recently returned after a long absence. I think.
3. The other main character is a man specialising in investigating supernatural/occult happenings in the town. He lives and/or works in a small basement apartment. No, it's not Mulder.
4. The male character's intense interest in the occult is motivated by the murder of his fiancée, naturally.
5. The female character also may have a romantic partner, though I don't think she was married. And whether or not the relationship lasted beyond the first episode is another thing I don't recall.

Comment: Do you have a locations for the show maybe? USA, Europe? A idea of the time (century?)

Comment: Probably the US or the UK, but I can't really recall any mentions of a specific location. Since I watched a dub I don't really know what accents the characters had to try and narrow it down. I just know it was dubbed from English. It both looked like it was filmed and took place in the early 2000s.

Comment: Now *that* is what I call adding details when you remember them. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though I *barely* remembered this, you're looking for the BBC show [Strange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_(TV_series)) that ran for 7 episodes back in 2003 and starred Richard Coyle and Samantha Womack.

> The series follows former priest John Strange, dismissed from the clergy under mysterious circumstances. He was implicated in a number of gruesome murders, murders that he says were done by demons. Now he seeks those responsible and to clear his name.

In episode 5 (*Dubik* or *Dubuykk*), people are found with all their blood drained. It turns out to be some sort of evil tree that affects people through timber and lures them with visions of deceased loved ones, which in one case is an old woman's dog, and in John's case is his dead fiancee. Here's a clip from that episode:

Comment: Yes, this is it! Thank you so much man! I've been trying to find out what this show was for years now. I'm obviously new here so I don't know the proper etiquette, but whatever upvotes or things of that nature you desire are yours - just say the word.

Comment: Approving it is more than enough. ;) Thanks for the detailed question, and glad you found your show!